# Unity how do i google sign in with firebase c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unfortunately on their site and everywhere else the only way to do this is through java not c#. Could anybody help me? Basically i just need a code in c# to do this :

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Comment: Hi, any one has got the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Apologies, re-writing answer!!

You'll need to install a third party plugin or make one yourself. I use Google's own plugin: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity

As described on their wiki, you'll need to set up a configuration for iOS and Android first. I recommend trying to get their sample to work before integrating the plugin into your own project.

Comment: Yes, this page shows me to do so  Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
    Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken); but i do not have the googleIdToken or the googleAccesdToken. I saw that page